# Column named COUNT issue

Tags: oracle

I have a table with a column named COUNT.

If I execute the following query:
Select count
From mytable

From SQL Developer it works fine.
From JDBC connection it does not work.

I can not modify the table structure...

Do you any idea how can I workaround this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This will help:

```
Select a.count from mytable a
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT` is a [reserved word](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm), so you need to escape it:

```
select "COUNT" 
from yourtable
```